# Fetch Random String From Array For Each New Form Entry

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

!Sheet1 is populated with entries coming from a Google form
!Sheet2 has an array of 12 employee names in array A2:A13

How can I automatically populate the cell on the right column of every new line form entry so it will display a random employee name to the right of every new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is this formula:

**`=INDEX(Sheet2!A2:A13; RANDBETWEEN(1; COUNTA(Sheet2!A2:A13)))`**